# The symbol is a weak symbol that has not been specifically tagged as a weak object symbol

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does the sentence

> The symbol is a weak symbol that has not been specifically tagged as a weak object symbol.

mean? What is the purpose of "specifically" here?

This is from nm's documentation.

For each symbol, nm shows:

The symbol type.

"w" The symbol is a weak symbol that has not been specifically tagged as a weak object symbol.  When a weak defined symbol is linked with a normal defined symbol, the normal defined symbol is used with no error.

Comment: Have you looked up _specifically_ in a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, but I'm still not sure about that sentence

Comment: Would it help if it said _explicitly_ rather than _specifically_? They mean the same in this instance.

Comment: It seems to me that either "specifically" or "explicitly" are just redundant here. That sentence makes perfect sense without either of these adverbs.

Comment: It makes sense without, but evidently would not make the point the author wanted to make without it. There's nothing wrong with redundancy.